# Characterize open sets

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Characterization of open sets in a space with countable number of basis elements and regular.

Comment: Earlier you had a regular space with a countable base, you changed it to metrizable? On purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $B_n, n \in \Bbb N$ be a countable base for $X$. Given an open set $U$, $$U=\bigcup \{ \overline{B_n}: \overline{B_n} \subseteq U\}$$ so $U$ is a countable union of closed sets. The right to left inclusion is trivial and the other is by regularity: if $x \in U$, there is an open set $O$ with $x \in O \subseteq \overline{O} \subseteq U$ by regularity and as the $B_n$ form a base there is some $n$ such that $x \in B_n \subseteq O$, and then, for that $n$, $\overline{B_n}$ (and thus $x$) occurs in the right hand union.

For a general metric space (a not second countable one) we can just use the metric $d$ that exists on $X$ and write $$U=\bigcup_n F_n, \text{ where } F_n = \{x \in U: d(x,X\setminus U) \le \frac{1}{n}\} \text{ is closed }$$

Comment: I am not able to understand, how you can write: $\textbf{then, for that $n$, $\overline{B_n}$ (and thus x) occurs in the right hand union.}$

Comment: @shakunimama I’m proving that all $x \in U$ also lie in the right hand union I wrote.

Comment: How is right to left inclusion is trivial ?

Comment: @shakunimama because of the definition! It’s a union of sets that are all subsets of $U$..

Comment: I am not sure how the trivial part holds true. Would you please provide a proof for that part.

Comment: @shakunimama if $x \in \bigcup \{ \overline{B_n}: \overline{B_n} \subseteq U\}$. then for some $n$ such that $\overline{B_n} \subseteq U$, $x \in \overline{B_n}$. So immediately $x \in U$. done.